# how to keep diverged form of a merged commit in a cherry-pick?

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I want to cherry-pick a range of commit and among them, there is a merged commit which when I want to cherry-pick my commits, this merged commit just get cherry-picked in a linear form but I want to keep its diverged form and to see which commits are the parents of this merged commit but this situation isn't possible in a linear history created by cherry-pick, so I was wondering if it is possible to keep our history diverged in a cherry-pick or if isn't possible, is there any other alternative in git?

command I used:

```
git cherry-pick (commit C hash)~1..(commit F hash)   (my head is pointing to test1)
```

Diagrams:

```
A--B--C--E--F--K (master)               Current history
    \  \   /
     J   D (test2)
    (test1)
```

```
A--B--C--E--F--K--T (master)             History after cherry-picking
    \  \   /
     J   D (test2)
      \
       C
        \
         D
          \
           E
            \
             F
             (test1)
```

```
A--B--C--E--F--K--T (master)             Expected history after cherry-picking
    \  \   /
     J   D (test2)
      \
       C
      / \
     D   E
      \   \ 
       \---F   
          (test1)
```

Comment: Do you want the parent of E to shift from C to D? Or is it a typo?

Comment: my bad, the last diagram was wrong, I revised that...@ElpieKay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is interactive reabse (`git rebase -i`).

```
 git rebase -i -r --onto J C~ F
 # The edit screen pops up. Just save and quit.
```

The expected history is created in a detached HEAD. Then update `test1` with this new HEAD.

```
git update-ref refs/heads/test1 HEAD
```

The commits C, D, E and F are rebased onto J. `-r/--rebase-merges` instructs to preserve the merge commit structure.

Comment: can't we just use `-i` and `--onto` get omitted? because I find --onto confusing...

Comment: @alex_121 if you don't want `-i` and `--onto`, consider @j6t 's answer. `-i` and `--onto` can deal with more generic cases, like the one that the parent of J is A instead of B and you still want to apply C, D, E, F. For `--onto X Y Z`, X is the new base, Y is the start commit (not included, or the parent of the first included commit) and Z is the end (included). It means to apply the set of commits (Y, Z] onto X. With the help of `-i`, we can do more like sorting, dropping, squashing, editing the commits.

Comment: I think I couldn't make myself understood, I mean what if we keep `-i` and just remove the `--onto`? does it make a difference? because I found `--onto` confusing and useless in this situation... @ElpieKay

Comment: @alex_121 Sorry, my bad. English is not my native language. `--onto` is necessary here. Without it, `git rebase -i -r C~ F` tries to apply C, D, E F onto C~ (B). It automatically picks B as the new base. However, the expected new base should be J.

Comment: @alex_121 By @j6t 's answer, test1 is first reset to F. Then `git rebase J test1` picks J as the new base, and tries to apply C, D, E, F onto J. In this method, the commits C, D, E, F are the result of `git log J..F`. In my method, the commits C, D, E, F are the result of `git log B..F`. They happen to be the same set of commits.

Comment: what if I pick those certain commits I want in `git rebase -i` ?even in that case I still need `--onto` option?

Comment: @alex_121 The certain commits are determined by the start commit and the end commit. The start commit is also the default new base. If the default new base is not what you expect, `--onto` is needed to specify a different commit. If the default new base is what you expect, `--onto` is optional.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `git rebase --rebase-merges`:

```
git branch -f test1 F
git rebase --rebase-merges J test1
```